# Scattering $u\bar{d} - c\bar{b}$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, scattering, quarks

I'm trying to define if the scattering $u\bar{d} \rightarrow c\bar{b}$ is possible in any of the fundamental interactions, I know that in QCD (channel t) is allowed because of the charge conservation, but I'm not sure if the gluon can change the flavor of the quark u into the c quark. The same thing happens with the channel t of the weak interactions using $Z^0$ as the propagator particle. 
Or maybe this process is only allowed in the channel *s* with a $W^+$ as the mediator particle

[image]
[image]

Comment: So the scattering process is not possible via strong interaction nor electromagnetic?

Comment: Since answering in the comments is not a good thing to do i will delete my comments and write an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Flavour-Change is **always** imposed by the weak interaction. Even more then that it is only possible for charged currents (so for interactions involving $W^+$ and $W^-$)

The strength of that flavor-changing property is given by the [CKM-Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabibbo%E2%80%93Kobayashi%E2%80%93Maskawa_matrix)

So it is not possible for the strong or the electromagnetic interaction. And not for interactions with only $Z$-Bosons. There are processes which seem to be flavor changing via neutral current ($Z$-Bosons) but these are actually also charged currents. See e.g. [Penguin Diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penguin_diagram)